# how to use str_replace with array

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I have this string:

```
Name: Ali [[BOOK]] 
Name: Maer [[BOOK]] 
Name: John [[BOOK]]
```

And this array:

```
<pre>Array ( [0] => Story [1] => Newspaper [2] => Mag ) </pre>
```

I want to replace `[[BOOK]]` with array values.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation**
First you need to search inside array which element you want to replace.
**str_replace** function accept arguments. eg.

```
$arr = array("Story","Newspaper","Mag");
```

For example,You want to replace the Story to timeline.

```
str_replace("Story","timeline",$arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i want the result like:
Name: Ali Story
Name: Maer Newspaper 
Name: John Mag

by using foreach or for etc.

Comment: Yes, but i dont success, i don't know what's wrong.